# ¿Como enviar 2 input y un arreglo de checkbox?

Tags: php, ajax, checkbox

Soy algo nueva programando, como puedo enviar 2 valores de `input` y un `arreglo` de `checkbox` por `Ajax` para hacer una modificación en la base de datos, los `checkbox` tienen los `ids` y los `input` tienen los `datos` para modificar.

Arreglo de `checkbox`:

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="pagos" name="pago[]" value="<?php echo $ver[0] ?>"/>
</td>
```

`Modal` donde están los `input`:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalPagar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" float-right><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Pagar cuentas</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <label>Fecha de Pago</label>
            <input type="text" name="" id="fechap" class="form-control input-sm">
            <label>Numero de cheque</label>
            <input type="text" name="" id="cheque" class="form-control input-sm">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" id="pagar">
                Pagar
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Deberías revisar el uso de AJAX en Javascript o Jquery. Existen muchos tutoriales que te pueden ayudar, incluido la documentación oficial: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. Te sugiero que intentes programarlo y que si te surge algún problema publiques una pregunta más concreta y que haga referencia a un problema más puntual. Lo que pides requeriría de una respuesta demasiado amplia para los estándares del sitio Web.

Comment: Viendo que tienes un modal, te recomendaría que integres todo en el mismo DOM, es mejor desde el punto de vista de la experiencia del usuario y más fácil de recoger todos los datos para enviarlos al servidor por medio de Ajax. Sobre el uso de Ajax aquí hay varias preguntas/respuestas que explican cómo hacerlo. Sugiero que mires en la [lista de preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax?sort=votes&pageSize=50) y veas si hay alguna que te puede servir al menos para empezar. Luego ensayas un código y si tienes problemas los planteas aquí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos como estas usando Jquery es mas facil lo puedes hacer algo así:

```js
function grabarDatos(){
  //obtengo los checkbox
  var seleccionados = []
  $("input[name='options[]']:checked").each(function ()
  {
      seleccionados.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
  });
  //valido que seleccione una opcion minimo
  if(seleccionados.length == 0){
   alert('Seleccione una opcion');
   return false;
  }
  //valido que escoja la fecha
 fecha = $("#exampleModal #fechap").val();
  if(fecha == '' || fecha == null){
   alert('Seleccione la fecha de pago.');
    return false;
  }
  //data para enviar por ajax
  data = {
   checkboxs :seleccionados,
    fecha:fecha
  }
  console.log(data);
}//end function grabarDatos
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
 Abrir Modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="1" />op1 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="2" />op1 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="3" />op2 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="4" />op3 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="5" />op4 <br>
        <label>Fecha de Pago</label>
            <input type="date" name="" id="fechap" class="form-control input-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="grabarDatos();">Grabar Datos</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
    

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Si te fijas en el boton grabar mando a llamar una función **grabarDatos** la misma es encargada de recoger los checkbox y los datos necesarios para posteriormente armar la data y esta la enviarias por ajax segun lo que necesites.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono de maravilla.