# ¿como enviar un array de checkbox por ajax a php?

Tags: php, ajax, array, checkbox

estoy intentando hacer una carta de comidas donde el usuario seleccione lo que va a pedir mediante checkbox, los seleccionados se envían a un script en php, donde se van a guardar en un archivo de texto plano como es el txt (pedido.txt).
Primeramente genere un formulario y lo enviaba por post a php y lo guardo en un texto(eso funcionó bien).

El problema es que pretendo enviar los checkbox seleccionados por ajax para que no se recargue la pagina.

Una vez solucionado eso, mi intención es incorporarle un objeto para seleccionar la cantidad de cada item, pero un problema a la vez.

este seria mi codigo en html:

```
</head>
<body>
<meta name="viewport" content=" width=device-width, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1"/>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&family=Playfair+Display&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rajdhani:wght@400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


        <header>
        <div class="img">
                <img src="Logo-Menu.png" style="width: 150px;">
        </div>
        </header>
        
    <form  action="#" method="post">

        <section class="contenedor-menu">
            <div class="contenedor-texto">

                                                        <li class="Cat-nom"> 
                                                            <span>Pizzas</span>
                                                        </li>
                    
                    <ol class="OL-Prod">
                        <li class="isprod">
                            <label for="cbox1" class="prod-nom">pizza</label>
                            <span class="prod-desc">(mostaza, muzzarella, tomate y cebolla)</span>
                            <span class="prod-prec">$170 <input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" name="check[]" value="'mesa 1'-Papas Birra $210 "></input></span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="mostrar"></li>
                        <li class="isprod">
                            <label for="cbox2" class="prod-nom">pizza</label>
                            <span class="prod-desc">(mostaza, muzzarella, tomate y cebolla)</span>
                            <span class="prod-prec">$170 <input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" name="check[]" value="'mesa 1'-Papas Birra $210 "></input></span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="isprod">
                            <label for="cbox3" class="prod-nom">pizza</label>
                            <span class="prod-desc">(mostaza, muzzarella, tomate y cebolla)</span>
                            <span class="prod-prec">$170 <input type="checkbox" id="cbox3" name="check[]" value="'mesa 1'-Papas Birra $210 "></input></span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="isprod">
                            <label for="cbox4" class="prod-nom">pizza</label>
                            <span class="prod-desc">(mostaza, muzzarella, tomate y cebolla)</span>
                            <span class="prod-prec">$170 <input type="checkbox" id="cbox4" name="check[]" value="'mesa 1'-Papas Birra $210 "></input></span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="isprod">
                            <label for="cbox5" class="prod-nom">pizza</label>
                            <span class="prod-desc">(mostaza, muzzarella, tomate y cebolla)</span>
                            <span class="prod-prec">$170 <input type="checkbox" id="cbox5" name="check[]" value="'mesa 1'-Papas Birra $210 "></input></span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="isprod">
                            <label for="cbox6" class="prod-nom">pizza</label>
                            <span class="prod-desc"> (mostaza, muzzarella, tomate y cebolla)</span>
                            <span class="prod-prec">$170 <input type="checkbox" id="cbox6" name="check[]" value="'mesa 1'-Papas Birra $210 "></input></span>
                        </li>
                <li class="isprod">
                            <label for="cbox8" class="prod-nom">pizza</label>
                            <span class="prod-desc">(mostaza, muzzarella, tomate y cebolla)</span>
                            <span class="prod-prec">$170 <input type="checkbox" id="cbox8" name="check[]" value="'mesa 1'-Papas Birra $210 "></input></span>
                        </li>
                    </ol>

            </div>      
        </section> 

                <div class="contenedor-btn1">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn1" name="Enviar" value="Enviar Pedido"></input>
                </div>

</form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

y este seria el codigo que estoy untentando usar para enviar los datos por ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ids = new Array();
                $('input[name="check[]"]:checked').each(function(){
                    ids.push($(this).val());
                }); 

$('.btn1').click(function(){
                var datastring = 'check='+ ids;
                $.ajax({
                 type: "post",
                 data: {datastring},
                 url: "script.php",
                 success : function(data) {
                 //console.log(data[0].id_acta);
                    }
                    });

</script>
```

El código que utilizo para enviar los datos por ajax me tira un error, en la consola me indica que se esperaba el cierre del input (justo al serrar la etiqueta script), dándome a entender que el input de esta linea:

```
                $('input[name="check[]"]:checked').each(function(){
```

me lo toma como una etiqueta input de html.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como enviar 2 input y un arreglo de checkbox?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/251499/como-enviar-2-input-y-un-arreglo-de-checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

buscando por todos lados por fin logre enviar los datos por ajax y guardarlos en un texto(mediante php),
utilize el siguiente codico por si alguien tiene el mismo problema:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $('.form').submit(function (ev) {
 $.ajax({
type: "post", 
url: "script.php",
data: $('.form').serialize(),
success: function (data) {
// alert('Datos enviados !!!');
 } 
});
ev.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

y en el script del php utilice el siguiente código:

```
<?php 
$salto = "\r\n";
if(!empty($_POST['check'])){
    foreach($_POST['check'] as $seleccion) {
        $FP = fopen("Mesa-1.txt", a);
        fwrite($FP, $seleccion.$salto);
                                            }
    fclose($FP);
    /*header('Location: prueba.html');*/
}else{
echo "<p><b>Por favor ordene algo para comer o beber!!</b></p>";
}
```

?>
El condicional en el script tenia como fin, generar una condición para no enviar datos si no se selecciona ningún checkbox, pero ya no funciona.. lo cual voy a tener que averiguar para generar esa condición..